# How can I convert return-value of Solidity contract function to List in python?

Tags: python, list, solidity, return-value

in Solidity, return-value code like:
`returns(address [] memory, string [] memory) or returns (address[][] memory)`

I use make_post_request to call contract function, data like:

```
method='eth_call',
params=[{
     'to': config['arbContract'],
     'data': c.encodeABI(fn_name='getTokensInfo', args=[tokens]),
}]
```

And 'result' in response is:
'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'....

seems it's a bytestring, then how can i parsing it to list in python

Answer (score 0):

- Say we consider the `swapExactTokensForTokens` method of `uniswapV2Router` which returns `uint[] memory amounts`.

```js
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
```

- Quoting from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34339/retrieve-the-value-returned-by-a-function-which-was-invoked-with-transact)
  Here is how I was able to resolve this problem:

1. In the Solidity contract, just before returning, I generate an event which contains the value about to be returned.
2. In the Python code, I extract the returned value with:

```py
[...]
data = router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        tokens[1].balanceOf(account),
        1,
        path,
        attacker,
        chain.time(),
        {"from": account},
    )

>>> int(web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(data.txid)["logs"][2]["data"], 16)
631376138468681379
```

- This will give us the value of `amount0Out`.
- You can see the `events` like this

```py
>>> data.events
{'Approval': [OrderedDict([('owner', '0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3'), ('spender', '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'), ('value', 4500000000000000000)])], 'Transfer': [OrderedDict([('from', '0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3'), ('to', '0xA68d9dd94574d286A75D39b1516b348620FfDCA0'), ('value', 500000000000000000)]), OrderedDict([('from', '0xA68d9dd94574d286A75D39b1516b348620FfDCA0'), ('to', '0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3'), ('value', 631376138468681379)])], 'Sync': [OrderedDict([('reserve0', 14368623861531318621), ('reserve1', 11844678011344678012)])], 'Swap': [OrderedDict([('sender', '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'), ('amount0In', 0), ('amount1In', 500000000000000000), ('amount0Out', 631376138468681379), ('amount1Out', 0), ('to', '0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3')])]}
```

- I'm using `eth-brownie`.